# xml ns0: prefix cant make the previous solutions work

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

i know there are several questions that are already answered about this topic but for some reason i cant make it work when i read the file.

this is the code i have

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import copy
etree.register_namespace("","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
etree.register_namespace("","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
#Estract the search set thats necesary
tree=etree.ElementTree()
tree.parse('Selection Sets.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
#QTO with one set name and properties as needed, same properties will be applied to the new elements
itree=etree.ElementTree()
itree.parse('New QTO one set.xml')
iroot=itree.getroot()
print (etree.tostring(iroot))
#----Extract the names to be used in the new sets
catcher=[]
temp=tree.findall('selectionsets/selectionset')
for child in temp:
    catcher.append(str(child.get("name")))
# print (catcher)
#----create new elements inside the QTO xml
'''itemp=iroot.findall("Takeoff/Catalog")
for isets in itemp:
    for icatch in catcher:
        col = copy.deepcopy(isets)
        col.set('Name','%s'%(icatch))
        iroot.find('Takeoff/Catalog/Item').append(col)'''
print (catcher[0])
otree = etree.ElementTree(iroot)
otree.write('Set QTO.xml')
```

---

this is the original xml file structure

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Takeoff xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://download.autodesk.com/us/navisworks/schemas/nw-TakeoffCatalog-10.0.xsd">
    <Catalog>
        <Item Name="Column Location D" WBS="1" Transparency="0.3" Color="-3887691" LineThickness="0.1" CatalogId="f9f30bfc-6c43-4b7b-a335-5c5c093b4165">
            <VariableCollection>
                <Variable Name="Length" Formula="=ModelLength" Units="Meter" />
                <Variable Name="Width" Formula="=ModelWidth" Units="Meter" />
                <Variable Name="Thickness" Formula="=ModelThickness" Units="Meter" />
                <Variable Name="Height" Formula="=ModelHeight" Units="Meter" />
                <Variable Name="Perimeter" Formula="=ModelPerimeter" Units="Meter" />
                <Variable Name="Area" Formula="=ModelArea" Units="SquareMeter" />
                <Variable Name="Volume" Formula="=ModelVolume" Units="CubicMeter" />
                <Variable Name="Weight" Formula="=ModelWeight" Units="Kilogram" />
                <Variable Name="Count" Formula="=1" />
            </VariableCollection>
        </Item>
    </Catalog>
    <ConfigFile>
        <Workbook xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://download.autodesk.com/us/navisworks/schemas/nw-TakeoffConfiguration-10.0.xsd" xmlns="">
            <GlobalConfiguration>
                <ConfigureFileType>ItemResources</ConfigureFileType>
                <UnitsSystem>Metric</UnitsSystem>
                <Currency>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Code></Code>
                    <Symbol></Symbol>
                </Currency>
                <Column Name="Object">
                    <Type>String</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="any"></Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Description1">
                    <Type>String</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="any"></Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Description2">
                    <Type>String</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="any"></Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="ModelLength">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="ModelWidth">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="ModelThickness">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="ModelHeight">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="ModelPerimeter">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="ModelArea">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="area">squaremeter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="ModelVolume">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="volume">cubicmeter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="ModelWeight">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Input</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="0"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="weight">kilogram</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Length">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1">=ModelLength</Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Width">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1">=ModelWidth</Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Thickness">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1">=ModelThickness</Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Height">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1">=ModelHeight</Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Perimeter">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1">=ModelPerimeter</Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length">meter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Area">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1">=ModelArea</Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="area">squaremeter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Volume">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1">=ModelVolume</Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="volume">cubicmeter</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Weight">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1">=ModelWeight</Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="weight">kilogram</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="Count">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="0" group="any">count</Units>
                </Column>
                <Column Name="PrimaryQuantity">
                    <Type>Number</Type>
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Value varies="1"></Value>
                    <Units varies="1" group="any"></Units>
                </Column>
            </GlobalConfiguration>
            <Table Name="ObjectResource">
                <ColumnRef Name="Object" />
                <ColumnRef Name="Description1" />
                <ColumnRef Name="Description2" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelLength" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelWidth" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelThickness" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelHeight" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelPerimeter" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelArea" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelVolume" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelWeight" />
                <ColumnRef Name="Length">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Width">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Thickness">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Height">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Perimeter">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Area">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="area"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Volume">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="volume"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Weight">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="weight"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Count">
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="PrimaryQuantity">
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
            </Table>
            <Table Name="StepResource">
                <ColumnRef Name="Length">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Width">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Thickness">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Height">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Perimeter">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Area">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="area"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Volume">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="volume"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Weight">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="weight"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Count" />
                <ColumnRef Name="PrimaryQuantity" />
            </Table>
            <Table Name="ObjectStep">
                <ColumnRef Name="Object" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelLength" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelWidth" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelThickness" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelHeight" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelPerimeter" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelArea" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelVolume" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelWeight" />
                <ColumnRef Name="Length">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Width">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Thickness">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Height">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Perimeter">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Area">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="area"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Volume">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="volume"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Weight">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="weight"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
            </Table>
            <Table Name="Step">
                <ColumnRef Name="Length">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Width">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Thickness">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Height">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Perimeter">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Area">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Volume">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Weight">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
            </Table>
            <Table Name="Object">
                <ColumnRef Name="Object" />
                <ColumnRef Name="Description1" />
                <ColumnRef Name="Description2" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelLength" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelWidth" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelThickness" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelHeight" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelPerimeter" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelArea" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelVolume" />
                <ColumnRef Name="ModelWeight" />
                <ColumnRef Name="Length">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Width">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Thickness">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Height">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Perimeter">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="length"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Area">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="area"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Volume">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="volume"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Weight">
                    <Formula varies="1"></Formula>
                    <Units varies="1" group="weight"></Units>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Count">
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="PrimaryQuantity">
                    <Purpose>Calculation</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
            </Table>
            <Table Name="Item">
                <ColumnRef Name="Length">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Width">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Thickness">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Height">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Perimeter">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Area">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Volume">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Weight">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Count">
                    <Formula varies="1">=1</Formula>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="PrimaryQuantity" />
            </Table>
            <Table Name="ItemGroup" />
            <Table Name="Resource">
                <ColumnRef Name="Length">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Width">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Thickness">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Height">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Perimeter">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Area">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Volume">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Weight">
                    <Purpose>RollUp</Purpose>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="Count">
                    <Formula varies="1">=1</Formula>
                </ColumnRef>
                <ColumnRef Name="PrimaryQuantity" />
            </Table>
            <Table Name="ResourceGroup" />
        </Workbook>
    </ConfigFile>
</Takeoff>
```

---

Part of the result so far

```
<ns0:Takeoff xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://download.autodesk.com/us/navisworks/schemas/nw-TakeoffCatalog-10.0.xsd">
        <ns0:Catalog>
            <ns0:Item CatalogId="f9f30bfc-6c43-4b7b-a335-5c5c093b4165" Color="-3887691" LineThickness="0.1" Name="Column Location D" Transparency="0.3" WBS="1">
                <ns0:VariableCollection>
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=ModelLength" Name="Length" Units="Meter" />
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=ModelWidth" Name="Width" Units="Meter" />
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=ModelThickness" Name="Thickness" Units="Meter" />
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=ModelHeight" Name="Height" Units="Meter" />
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=ModelPerimeter" Name="Perimeter" Units="Meter" />
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=ModelArea" Name="Area" Units="SquareMeter" />
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=ModelVolume" Name="Volume" Units="CubicMeter" />
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=ModelWeight" Name="Weight" Units="Kilogram" />
                    <ns0:Variable Formula="=1" Name="Count" />
                </ns0:VariableCollection>
            </ns0:Item>
        </ns0:Catalog>
        <ns0:ConfigFile>
            <Workbook noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://download.autodesk.com/us/navisworks/schemas/nw-TakeoffConfiguration-10.0.xsd">
</Workbook>
    </ns0:ConfigFile>
</ns0:Takeoff>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and what is not working?

Comment: im trying to add new "Items" using elements from another xml. but before doing that i need to get the ns0: out of the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the problem now, you have unwanted ns0 prefixes in your output. In order to avoid them you may need to register all the namespaces with their corresponding prefixes:

```
etree.register_namespace("xs","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
etree.register_namespace("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
etree.register_namespace("","http://download.autodesk.com/us/navisworks/schemas/nw-TakeoffCatalog-10.0.xsd")
```

Comment: Thanks man ! didnt know i had to register the last xsd too. !! kudos for you